# Different ports for different servers in nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I have a rails application running with puma on port 3000. Client has a staging env with traffic coming in on 443 and a production env that uses 8080. Is there a way to pass the traffic from 443 to 3000 only in the staging env and from 8080 to 3000 only in the production env?

```
http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    proxy_pass_request_headers on;

    server {
        listen  8080;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host '$forwarded_host:$forwarded_port';
            proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            proxy_redirect  default;
        }

        location /healthcheck {
            return 404;
        }

        location /metrics {
            return 404;
        }

        location /ping {
            return 404;
        }
    }
```